# Specs2 and @Before/@After-like methods

Tags: scala, specs2

Given the code like:

```
class RESTAcceptanceTest extends Specification {

  override def is = anonymous ^ signinOAuth

  def anonymous = "Something"       ^ givenSomething ^
                  "must happen"     ^ mustHappen 
  end

  def signinOAuth = "Signin"                ^ givenSignin ^
                    "works as expected"     ^ userExistsInDatabase 
  end

  // rest of object definitions

}
```

how do I ensure that same before and after code is executed before/
after "anonymous" *and* "signinOAuth", and the "after" method should
execute even if test is failing itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Given/When/Then steps you can use a [Context](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Contexts) to control what gets executed before and after each example:

```
import org.specs2._
import specification._

class MySpec extends Specification { def is = 
  "anonymous" ^ 
    "something" ^ something ^
    "must happen" ^ mustHappen ^ endp^
  "OAuth"^ 
    "signing" ^ signing ^
    "works ok" ^ worksOk

  lazy val something: Given[Int] = (s: String) => { s.pp; 1 } 
  lazy val mustHappen: Then[Int] = (i: Int) => (s: String)  => 
    context { s.pp; i must_== 1       }

  lazy val signing:  Given[Int] = (s: String) => { s.pp; 2 }
  lazy val worksOk: Then[Int] = (i: Int) => (s: String) => 
    context { s.pp; i must_== 2 }

  lazy val context = new BeforeAfter {
   def  before = "before".pp
   def after = "after".pp
  }
}
```

In the code above the `apply` method of the `context` object is used to wrap the code to execute with `before` and `after`. Also if you add an error to one of the examples you will see that the "after" code is always executed.

PS: `pp` is a utility method like `println` to display something in the terminal during the execution. The advantage over println is that it returns its argument so you can write `1.pp must_== 1`

Comment: Thanks! I did almost like this but didn't find out how to deal with contexts. I would wish to update Specs2 user-guide with this example.

Comment: I have updated the documentation but also enabled the use of the `BeforeExample`, `AfterExample`,... traits with Given/When/Then steps (in 1.12.4-SNAPSHOT for Scala 2.9.2 and 1.13.1-SNAPSHOT for Scala 2.10). See the documentation: http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide-SNAPSHOT/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the documentation: http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Before/After

Comment: Actually I don't understand how that should work. I am using specifications with given/when/then sequences, so I don't understand how to wrap that BeforeAfter trait around it.

Comment: this should work: https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6/org.specs2.guide.Contexts.html